# Xamarin iOS External Accessory: check whether hands free device (car) is available

Tags: xamarin, bluetooth, xamarin.ios, external-accessory

I want my app to detect the Hands-Free built in the car. I don't need to communicate with the device, I just need to check if it is available.

> Ex: I want to send a notification when an Hands-Free is available on the vehicle.

I got this working with **CoreBluetooth** but it only works with BT4/BLE. Do I need to use **EAAccessoryManager** for old Bluetooth devices (version 2.0)? How can I implement this? I did try the code below but does not work:

```
var _accessoryList = EAAccessoryManager.SharedAccessoryManager.ConnectedAccessories;

foreach (EAAccessory acc in _accessoryList)
{
    // devices
}
```

The list **_accessoryList** is always empty.

The *info.plist* contains the background mode **External accessory communication** and the key **UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols** which I am not sure what should be the value to put in.

Any help? what am I missing? Thanks

Comment: refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10178293/how-to-get-list-of-available-bluetooth-devices ,maybe help

Comment: I'm wondering if it wouldn't be better to check the AudioRoutes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678249/routing-iphone-audio-sound